# How to display django roles and permissions in a custom dashboard

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to have roles, groups, and permissions in my custom admin dashboard (not the django admin) so as to assign roles, groups, and permissions. The django admin page for permissions looks like the image below. I want to have exact same permissions in my template.

[image]

In other frameworks like laravel, they have it done beautifully with the Spatie package. Is there any similar package too in Django or I have to write every single logic myself. Or better still can I query the Django-admin permissions and groups and display them in my custom admin dashboard template.

Answer (score 0):

Django permission and group models can be imported:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, Group
```

they are normal models like any other so you can query them:

```
Permission.objects.all()
```

You can also create other permissions:

```
from myapp.models import BlogPost
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(BlogPost)
permission = Permission.objects.create(
    codename='can_publish',
    name='Can Publish Posts',
    content_type=content_type,
)
```

All you need to do is to create endpoints for listing, adding and any other requirements that you might need.

More on Django docs: [Programmatically creating permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions)

Comment: Brilliant. This is a good start for me. Furthermore, can you add any resources or tutorials to guide me to implement a full-blown roles-permission dashboard? I'm stuck a bit how to do it

Comment: I don't think you can find many tutorials for this specific use case. It's just another API that you have to create. Take a look at DRF: https://www.django-rest-framework.org